# Adding translations for the models in the Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am new to ROR. I am trying add translations to my application. I have added translations for the controllers.

1. Where to add translations for models as i am not having any /config/locales -> models folder ->en.yml file .
2. In the model i am having lines like 
   validates_presence_of :name, :message => "Name cannot be blank!"

If i want to add translations for the message "Name cannot be blank", shall i put directly as like

validates_presence_of :name, :message => I18n.t(str_name_notblank)

Please give suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add translations to your models you just need to put them under `activerecord->models` and `activerecord->attributes`. Here's an example in polish:

```
pl:      
  activerecord:
    models:
      patient: "Pacjent"
    attributes:
      patient:
        first_name: "Imię"
        last_name: "Nazwisko"
        address: "Ulica"
        postal_code: "Kod"
        city: "Miejscowość"
```

Note that the `attributes` element is **not** under the `patient` element, but actually includes it again. I found this after some debugging and it actually worked for me. The [Rails I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) suggested a different structure, but it didn't work.

The best way to translate standard Rails messages (like the ones for validation) is to download the correct translation file from Sven Fuchs' [Rails Locale Data Repository (rails-18n)](http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale/) and put it into your `config/locales` folder (you can change the name). Then you'd remove your `:message` string and just use the standard messages, but translated to your liking.